# remove Key:value pair from json file using shell script

Tags: regex, linux, sed

Below is the content of file1.json amongst many json file in the directory,

```
{
  "options": {
    "create": "cycletime"
  },
  "indexes": [... some data]
}
```

I need a regex to delete the object that contains `"options"` as key and the expected json looks like below, (json must be affect with changes)

```
{
  "indexes": [... some data]
}
```

Comment: What is your problem with your current solutions (if any)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `jq` and its `del` function:

```
jq 'del(.options)' file.json
```

Comment: @AnkurSoni: They aren't going to work reliably. Also, who defines which packages are already installed?

Comment: I mean when you install a raw copy of iso on virtualbox. It should work with basic minimal package.